# Why is the bottom border of the output number messed up in my scientific notation converter?

Tags: javascript, html, css

This is my current project: https://output.jsbin.com/zajocom

My code works decently (although yes, it is not the best code - I'm still a beginner). However, with big numbered exponents, the bottom of the green border gets messed up on Chrome. The specific example I have is 9.245 for the number, and -9000000 as the exponent. This is an image of my issue:
[image]

Is there any way to fix something like this?

This is my code (when placed in one HTML file):

```js
function addCommas(num) {
  return num.toString().replace(/(\d)(?=(\d\d\d)+(?!\d))/g, '$1,');
}

function outputNumberForm() {
  var numberInput = document.getElementById("numberInput");
  var exponentInput = document.getElementById("exponentInput");
  var outputId = document.getElementById("output");

  var editedNumberInput = numberInput;

  var multiplierNumber = (numberInput.value.split('.')[1] || []).length;
  var zeroCount = "0";
  var multiplierCount = "";
  var outputText;

  if (exponentInput.value % 1 != 0) {
    outputId.style.border = `5px solid red`;
    outputId.style.backgroundColor = `white`;
    outputId.style.width = `300px`;
    outputId.innerHTML = "Please put a whole number as an exponent.";
  } else if (numberInput.value * 1000 % 1 != 0) {
    outputId.style.border = `5px solid red`;
    outputId.style.backgroundColor = `white`;
    outputId.style.width = `300px`;
    outputId.innerHTML = "The maximum amount of decimals is three digits.";
  } else if (Math.floor(Math.abs(numberInput.value / 10)) != 0) {
    outputId.style.border = `5px solid red`;
    outputId.style.backgroundColor = `white`;
    outputId.style.width = `300px`;
    outputId.innerHTML = `Please put only a ones digit (Ex: "2.31" instead of "23.1")`;
  } else if (exponentInput.value == 0) {
    outputId.style.border = `5px solid #1ac729`;
    outputId.style.backgroundColor = `white`;
    outputId.style.width = `300px`;
    outputId.innerHTML = "Your number in regular form is:<br>" + numberInput.value;
  } else {
    outputId.style.border = `5px solid #1ac729`;
    outputId.style.backgroundColor = `white`;
    outputId.style.width = `300px`;
    outputId.style.wordWrap = `break-word`;

    for (let i = 0; i < multiplierNumber; i++) {
      multiplierCount = multiplierCount + "0";
    }
    multiplierCount = "1" + multiplierCount;
    editedNumberInput = numberInput.value * multiplierCount;


    if (exponentInput.value == -1) {
      if (numberInput.value < 0) {
        outputId.innerHTML = "Your number in regular form is:<br>" + "-0." + String(Math.abs(editedNumberInput)).replace(/\./g, '');
      } else {
        outputId.innerHTML = "Your number in regular form is:<br>" + "0." + String(editedNumberInput).replace(/\./g, '');
      }
    } else if (exponentInput.value < 0) {
      for (let i = 2; i < Math.abs(exponentInput.value); i++) {
        zeroCount = zeroCount + "0";
      }
      if (numberInput.value < 0) {
        outputId.innerHTML = "Your number in regular form is:<br>" + "-0." + zeroCount + String(Math.abs(editedNumberInput)).replace(/\./g, '');
      } else {
        outputId.innerHTML = "Your number in regular form is:<br>" + "0." + zeroCount + String(editedNumberInput).replace(/\./g, '');
      }

    } else if (exponentInput.value - multiplierNumber > 0) {
      for (let i = 1; i < (exponentInput.value - multiplierNumber); i++) {
        zeroCount = zeroCount + "0";
      }
      outputId.innerHTML = "Your number in regular aform is:<br>" + addCommas(String(editedNumberInput).replace(/\./g, '') + String(zeroCount));
    } else if (exponentInput.value - multiplierNumber < 0) {
      outputText = (Math.round((numberInput.value * 10 ** exponentInput.value) * (10 ** Math.abs(exponentInput.value - multiplierNumber)))) / (10 ** Math.abs(exponentInput.value - multiplierNumber));
      outputId.innerHTML = "Your number in regular form is:<br>" + outputText;
    } else if (exponentInput.value - multiplierNumber == 0) {
      outputText = addCommas(String(numberInput.value).replace(/\./g, ''));
      outputId.innerHTML = "Your number in regular form is:<br>" + outputText;
    }
  }
}
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  user-select: none;
}

body {
  background-color: #01a50f;
}

h1 {
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
  margin-bottom: 70px;
}

h2 {
  color: white;
}

.container {
  margin: auto;
  width: fit-content;
}

.big-row-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.row-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  margin: 20px;
}

#button {
  margin: 60px auto 0px auto;
  background-color: #03750d;
  border: 3px solid white;
  border-radius: 5px;
  color: white;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: block;
  font-size: 15px;
  padding: 5px;
  text-align: center;
}

#output {
  background-color: none;
  padding: 5px;
  margin: 20px auto;
  border-radius: 15px;
  width: 400px;
  text-align: center;
  user-select: text;
}

#numberInput {
  height: fit-content;
  width: 100px;
  font-size: 20px;
}

#exponentInput {
  height: fit-content;
  width: 100px;
  font-size: 20px;
}

.label-description {
  font-size: 20px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Scientific Notation Converter</title>
</head>

<body>
  <h1>Scientific Notation Converter</h1>

  <div class="container">
    <h2 style="text-align: center;">Express scientific notation in regular number form.</h2>

    <div class="big-row-container">
      <div class="row-container">
        <label class="label-description" for="numberInput">Input number (Ex: "2.31" from 2.31 x 10<sup>7</sup>):&nbsp;</label>
        <input type="number" step="1" id="numberInput" name="numberInput">
      </div>

      <div class="row-container">
        <label class="label-description" for="exponentInput">Input exponent (Ex: "7" from 2.31 x 10<sup>7</sup>):&nbsp;</label>
        <input type="number" step="1" id="exponentInput" name="exponentInput">
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>

  <button id="button" onclick="outputNumberForm()">Calculate</button>

  <p id="output"></p>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Seems to be working fine for me, using Safari on Macbook. What browser are you using?

Comment: Using Chrome (and Edge) on Windows 10 it is fine.

Comment: @AntonThomas I am using the most up to date version of Google Chrome running on Windows 10. Did you put my example numbers in?

Comment: I put the exact same numbers in, maybe try restarting Chrome/ your machine to see if it's any different? I suspect it's a browser error.

Comment: I've also got Chrome on Windows 10 and can't duplicate the problem. By "most up to date version", can we assume you mean the most recent **stable** version, not dev?

Comment: I have dev edge (canary version) 95.0.997.0 and works fine. Tried also on edge´s stable version (92.0.902.78) and also looks good.

Comment: @Cat Yes, most stable version that normal people use

Comment: I neither find issues using Chrome nor Mozilla Firefox nor MS Edge...